Question on Arnold's proof of the Abel-Ruffini Theorem
I am reading Arnold's proof from this paper by Leo Goldmakher.
I think I have understood how the existence of single radicals in the cubic formula is ruled out in section 4, however, I don't understand why the same logic can't be applied again to rule out nesting of two radicals in the cubic formula (even though that would be incorrect).
Here is what I have understood so far:

There exists a loop in function space based at $p$ inducing any permutation of the roots of the corresponding separable polynomial in the complex plane. These permutations can sometimes be explained by the fact that $p$ could be on a different branch to which it started.
A certain type of loop can be constructed using commutators. This loop leaves $p$ on the same branch as it started.
Since $p$ is on the same branch, given any continuous function $f$ mapping $p$ from the function space to the complex plane, the result $f(p)^\alpha$ (for some rational $\alpha$) will also complete a loop as $p$ traverses the commutator's path.
However, in the case of the cubic, the commutator of (1 2 3) and (1 2) induces a permutation of (1 3 2), which means the roots do not travel a full loop as suggested previously. This means the cubic formula cannot be of the form $f(p)^\alpha$. So, instead, there must be a nesting of radicals.

What I do not understand is why this logic cant be repeating again to say the cubic formula cannot have a double nesting of radicals either.

Since after one commutator $p$ is on the same branch as it started, given a continuous functions $f_{1},f_{2}$ as before, the result of $\sqrt[\alpha_{1}]{f_{1}(p)+\sqrt[\alpha_{2}]{f_{2}}(p)}$ should also return to the same value it had at the start of the commutator ie: complete a loop. Then, the existence of (1 3 2) as a permutation induced by a commutator means that this expression cannot be in the cubic formula, so, any cubic formula must have 3 or more radicals nested, which is definitely wrong.

I'm unsure though as to where this is wrong. Why, when we try to rule out nesting of level 2, do we have to use commutators of commutators (which only result in 1 trivial permutation for 3 roots, thus preventing us from ruling out nesting level 2 for cubics). Why do we have to go to using commutators of commutators in the first place though? Can't we just use commutators since they preserve the branch $p$ is on. How would a commutator of commutators be any different to just using commutators as in the previous case?

I really recommend the YouTube Video Why there's 'No' Quintic Formula by "not all wrong". It specifically explains Vladimir Arnold's argument for the non-existence of a general algebraic formula for solving quintic equations.

@ReinhardMeier Thanks for the video, however, even after the bit in the video about why nested roots aren't enough (28:29), I still don't get why the outer root is also not single valued after the commutator is applied. After a commutator won't both $f_{1}(p)$ and $\sqrt[\alpha_{2}]{f_{2}(p)}$ return to their exact original values on the same branch they started on, so then taking a root of that should also return the final value to its original value?
